# combining two list of values into a data frame: error arguments imply differing number of rows

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have two lists that I would like to combine into a dataframe. The lists follows this basic logic. list1 contains name of countries and list2 contains values exctracted from each value in list1.

```
list1<-list("A", "C", "B")
list2<-list(c("la la", "po sdfejn kfgndñflgn"), "characther(0)", c("4   5","baby", "yeah")) # note that characther(0) means that there is no data
```

The outcome I want is like this:

```
output <- data.frame( V1 = c(rep("A",2), "C", rep("B",3)), V2 = c("la la", "po sdfejn kfgndñflgn", "characther(0)", "4   5", "baby", "yeah"))
```

I have used codes that I have seen in this page such as: `solution1 <- do.call(rbind, Map(data.frame, a = list1, b= list2))`as I often do. This code works for the example. However, I obtain the following error message when I use this formula for the large lists I am working on, :

> ```
> Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = 
> TRUE,  : arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0
> ```

I have tried to `unlist(list1), unlist(list1)` but it does not work. If both list are identical, where is really the source of problem and how can I solve in order to have the desired output?

Comment: I don't see how your expected output is connected to your sample data. None of the entries seem to match. Please provide expected output that is based on your sample data.

Comment: I am afraid this is not a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). With your code and sample data, I get neither your error message nor the expected output. Please provide sample data that replicate your problem and explain the rules for your expected output.

Comment: sorry, I edit it

Comment: Please see my updated answer. I think I can generate your expected output except that `A` should only repeat two times.

Comment: Please see my update again. I have changed my answer based on your latest update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution using `tidyverse`. `dat` is the final output.

```
library(tidyverse)

dat <- map2_df(list1, list2, ~data_frame(V1 = .x, V2 = .y))
dat
# # A tibble: 6 x 2
#   V1    V2                  
#   <chr> <chr>               
# 1 A     la la               
# 2 A     po sdfejn kfgndñflgn
# 3 C     characther(0)       
# 4 B     4   5               
# 5 B     baby                
# 6 B     yeah
```

Comment: hi, it works. The problem i have with this code and my data is that cases similar to C are deleated. Is there a way to keep it?

Comment: If it works on your example dataset, it should work on your real-world dataset. The logical conclusion is your example data frame cannot represent your real-world dataset. I would suggest you accept my post as the answer and ask a new question with example dataset truly represents your real-world data.

Comment: I solve the problem. Since "characther(0)" an empty cell, i run this ```lapply(corporate.info, function(x) if(identical(x, character(0))) NA_character_ else x)``` before your code. Thanks!